# Generating a set of files containing dumps of individual tables in a way that guarantees database consistency

Tags: sql, locking, mysql

I'd like to dump a MySQL database in such a way that a file is created for the definition of each table, and another file is created for the data in each table.  I'd like this to be done in a way that guarantees database integrity by locking the entire database for the duration of the dump.  What is the best way to do this?  Similarly, what's the best way to lock the database while restoring a set of these dump files?

#### edit

I can't assume that mysql will have permission to write to files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InnoDB tables and therefore have transaction support, you don't need to lock the database at all you can just add the [`--single-transaction`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) command line option.  This gives you a consistent snapshot without locking anything by using the transaction mechanism.

If you don't have transaction support you can get what you describe with the [`--lock-tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables) command line option, this will lock the databases.

It's also worth noting that READ LOCKs aren't quite as good as they sound since any write operation will lock which will lock subsequent read operations, see [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/04/24/how-fast-is-flush-tables-with-read-lock/) for more detials

**Edit:**
I don't think it's possible to dump the format and data separately without the file writing permission and the [`--tab`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab) option.  I think your only option is to roll your own `mysqldump` script that uses one of the transaction or READ LOCK mechanisms that mysqldump uses.  Failing that it may be easier to just postprocess a single dumpfile into the format you want.

Comment: Is there a library in some language that can reliably generate a dump of a given table?  Or maybe some way to pass an open DB connection to mysqldump?

Comment: Any MySQL client library in whatever your preferred language should let you run a LOCK TABLE command, or START TRANSACTION before SELECTing the data out, you then just need to write the row data out in INSERT statement format. SHOW CREATE TABLE foo will give you the structure.

Comment: based on the fact that `mysqldump`'s dumps contain commands other than INSERT, I'd say it's a bit more complex than that.  Setting the character set is one thing that comes to mind.  There are a lot of things to take into consideration, probably depending on the table type, and particular use cases, that I wouldn't want to have to attempt to itemize and deal with.